# Do we need to upload two separate builds (Android) for 32- bit and 64- bit architecture to Play store?

Tags: android

Upload two separate builds (Android) for 32- bit and 64- bit architecture to Play store?

Comment: No, go with single build!

Comment: that's up to you. You can include support of both into single APK

Answer (score 0):

If your APK is not too big (much less than 100mb), you can do not care about separating your build. But if your application is big and you are closing to 100mb limit, you should think about [App bundle](https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle). In short you pack your bundle and upload it to Google Play. It automatically prepare some APKs for any architecture, languages and other different params. Each APK will include only .so files for a specific architecture.

Good luck!